# how to add specnames to rankabuncomp?

Tags: r, plot, vegan

I am trying to add the species names to the `rankabuncomp` plot. I tried to add `specnames = T` to the `rankabundance` function but I get an error. Please help me work around this problem. Thanks a lot.

```
library(vegan)
library(BiodiversityR)
data(dune.env)
data(dune)
RankAbun.1 <- rankabundance(dune)
RankAbun.1
rankabunplot(RankAbun.1,scale='abundance', addit=FALSE, specnames=c(1,2,3))
rankabuncomp(dune, y=dune.env, factor='Management', scale='proportion',   legend=FALSE)
#to add specnames
rankabuncomp(dune, y=dune.env, factor='Management', specnames=c(1,2,3), scale='proportion', legend=FALSE, labels=FALSE)
```

Comment: What are the package you use? You only load **vegan**, but it has none of these functions (no `rankabundance`, `rankabunplot`or `rankabuncomp` in **vegan**).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I used `biodiversityR`. I've updated my question.

Comment: The pakcage is `BiodiversityR` with uppercase first letter: I tried to correct this, but stackoverflow does not allow corrections that are shorter than six characters and I could not change just the one that was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BiodiversityR::rankabuncomp` explicitly disallows adding species names. This is hardcoded in the function and cannot be changed without editing the function (look for `specnames = NULL`  in `rankabunplot()` calls). The help page does not give `specnames` argument to `rankabuncomp` so that this is also documented. I can understand this decision: `rankabuncomp`  draws several lines in one graph, and often these are so similar that species names would overwrite each other and the plot becomes unreadable.

To add the lines, you either need edit the function or you must use a series of `rankabunplot` commands to overlay graphs in one plot. Here is an example how to do that with the `dune` data:

```
library(BiodiversityR)
data(dune, dune.env)
## list of models
mods <- with(dune.env, lapply(levels(Management), function(lev)
    rankabundance(dune, dune.env, 'Management', lev)))
## level 4 seems to be most extreme: draw it first 
rankabunplot(mods[[4]],scale='abundance', addit=FALSE, specnames=c(1,2,3))
## add the rest
## change colour etc to separate the lines if wished
rankabunplot(mods[[3]],scale='abundance', addit=TRUE, specnames=c(1,2,3))
rankabunplot(mods[[2]],scale='abundance', addit=TRUE, specnames=c(1,2,3))
rankabunplot(mods[[1]],scale='abundance', addit=TRUE, specnames=c(1,2,3))
```

The resulting plot is not very readable. If you use proportional scaling of y-axis, it becomes even less readable. However, you *can* do it.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I really appreciate it.